# Possible to store a value in variable in SPSS?

Tags: variables, syntax, spss

Is is possible in SPSS to store a value in a variable (not a variable created in a data set)?

For example I have a loop for which I want to pass the value 4 to all the locations in the loop that say `NumLvl`.

```
NumLvl = 4.
VECTOR A1L(NumLvl-1).
LOOP #i = 1 to NumLvl-1.
COMPUTE A1L(#i) = 0.
IF(att1 = #i) A1L(#i) = 1.
IF(att1 = NumLvl) A1L(#i) = -1.
END LOOP.
EXECUTE.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `DEFINE / !ENDDEFINE` SPSSs Macro Facility, for example:

```
DEFINE !MyVar () 4 !ENDDEFINE.
```

You can then use `!MyVar` as a substitute for 4 wherever in your syntax you wish.

See [`DEFINE / !ENDDEFINE`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_define.htm) documentation for further notes.